# ComboBox empty even after adding elements

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I created a ComboBox and added elements into it but it always shows up blank. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

My FXML file:

```
<GridPane fx:id="gridEdits"
              style="-fx-padding: 10 10 10 10" hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <Label GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
            Starting Time After: </Label>
        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
                   fx:id="tfShowingID" editable="false"/>

        <Label GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            Ending Time Before:</Label>
        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
                   fx:id="tfVenue" editable="false"/>

        <Label GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            Advisory Rating:</Label>
        <SearchableComboBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"
                            fx:id="selector" editable="true"/> </GridPane>
```

And in my Java file:

```
public SearchableComboBox<String> selector;   
ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList("14 Accompaniment (14A)", "18 
ccompaniment (18A)","General (G)", "Parent Guidance (PG)", "Restricted (R)", "Unrated (U)");
selector = new SearchableComboBox<>(data);
```

Comment: In your FXML file you have `fx:id="selector"`. In the snippet of Java code you provided you have a field named `selector`. Assuming that code is part of the FXML controller then you must not assign a new instance to `selector`; the `FXMLLoader` will inject the instance. Your instance is not the one shown on screen.

Comment: did you set the controller of your fxml file: <GridPane fx:id="gridEdits"
              style="-fx-padding: 10 10 10 10" hgap="10" vgap="10"
              fx:controller="MyFxmlController">